# How to reduce memory usage of python os.listdir for large number of files

Tags: python

I am using `os.listdir()` to get the list of a directory.
I would like to find a nice way of get list of files in a directory with limited number of files if specified.

`os.listdir()` works nice but it does not have a way to limit number of scan and as a result sometimes it cause kill process by out-of-memory.

`os.listdir(path)` works well.

It generates a long-list as big as the number of files in a directory, e.g.:

100 entry if 100 files in a directory.

1000 entry if 1000 files in a directory.

## It means it returns bigger list depending on the number of files in a directory. And sometimes it causes process kill by using too big memory.

But what happens if there's over one million files in a directory?

Searched `os.listdir(), os.scandir(), os.walk()` but they does not support limit number of files to search.

```
dirs = os.listdir( path )
print( len(dirs) )
```

So, I expect a function as like, which can save the memory.

### OLD WAY

```py
list = os.listdir(path)   # return full list of files in a path
```

### NEW WAY

```
list = os.listdir(path, maxscan=100)  # return list of files max 100 files in a path.
```

Comment: Why not use [os.scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) instead?  It returns an iterator rather than a list.

Comment: Ok didn't saw you mention that you already tested `os.scandir`. In my opinion, to work on large number of files, this is the correct solution. It's the rest of the code that needs to be adapted to work with `os.scandir()`

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `for c, path in enumerate(os.scandir()):if c >  100:break`?

Comment: Hi Mathieu,  Gloweye,     using code like "os.scandir()  if c> 100 " means it neet to get full list before return maximum 100 entries.

Comment: @CHJ. No it doesn't. You need to look up iterators and generators and how they work.

Comment: What kind of ridiculously huge quantities of files are you dealing with such that this could actually use up all your memory? 100 million files in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `glob.iglob` and loop over the generator:

```
for f in glob.iglob('subdir/*'):
    print(f)
```

**Source**: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Additionally, if you do want to process the files in batches of, say 100, you can easily modify the code above to do that:

```
folder_contents = glob.iglob('subdir/*')
for _, f in zip(range(100), folder_contents):
    print(f)
```

Comment: What happens if I have 1,000,000 files in a directory?  I have limited memory(RAM).

Comment: @CHJ that shouldn't be a problem, because if you're iterating over a single item at a time, you'll only ever have a single filename in the memory. The rest are waiting to be loaded. One thing you should be cautious about is that the directory contents don't change while you're processing it. It may not generate an error, but it'll probably give you unpredictable results.